# How to execute ACL changes that Server.app makes to shares from shell?

Tags: terminal, permission, server.app, sharing, acl

I have a situation where Server.app works for many hours, never seeming to finish, when applying permissions on a large share.

What is the shell incantation that would apply read + write access to a specific user for an entire share?

`ls -le` shows the following permissions:

```
 0: user:admin allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
 1: group:admin allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
 2: user:_spotlight allow list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit
 3: user:myusername allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit
 4: user:_spotlight allow list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit
 5: user:myusername allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit
 6: user:_spotlight allow list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit
 7: user:myusername allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit
 8: user:_spotlight allow list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit
 9: user:myusername allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit
 10: user:_spotlight allow list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit
 11: user:myusername allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit
 12: user:_spotlight allow list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit
 13: user:myusername allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit
 14: user:_spotlight allow list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit
 15: user:myusername allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit
 16: user:_spotlight allow list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit
 17: user:_spotlight allow list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit
 18: user:_spotlight allow list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit
 19: user:myusername allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit
```

But I'm not entirely sure if I should assemble a script that mimics these kinds of permissions or if there's a simpler, and more preferable way, to do this.

***Update: I did find an interesting incantation going on in the background that was executed by Server.app:***
`/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/servermgrd/bundles/server mgr_sharing.bundle/Contents/copyprivs -p /Volumes/path_to_share -f 32 -s /tmp/CopyPrivsTemp.B251lF`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>parentPath</key>
  <string>/Volumes/path_to_share</string>
  <key>status</key>
  <string>running</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Help for `copyprivs`:

```
Usage:
must be run as root

Deprecated Panther copy function:

-o <owner> : Owner name
-g <group> : Group name
-p <path>  : Path name
-m <mode>  : permissions mode in octal
Tiger propagate function:

-p <path>  : Path name
-f <flags>  : flag:
propagate UID  1 << 0
propagate GID  1 << 1
propagate ModeOwner  1 << 2
propagate ModeGroup  1 << 3
propagate ModeWorld  1 << 4
propagate ACL  1 << 5
```

Comment: Why did you delete your latest question ([How to reset permissions across a filesystem after catastrophic problems?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284526/how-to-reset-permissions-across-a-filesystem-after-catastrophic-problems))?

Comment: @klanomath I fixed most of the issues and I'm now just sorting out `/var/folder` permission issues so I didn't feel the question was really pertinent any longer the way I framed it. If and when I get this entirely resolved I'll post a wiki about it. Right now I'm thinking about going into single user mode and mv'ing the folders to allow the OS to recreate them, but that's what I'm fiddling with atm.